# How to disable duration using media3

Tags: android, android-mediasession, android-media3

I'm trying to use media3 to play music on the background.

What I want is **not to show the duration** like the image.
[image: media3 example]

Does anyone know how to do this?
I'm currently using
MediaSession, ExoPlayer, MediaController.

I've try using

```
MediaSession.ConnectionResult.AcceptedResultBuilder(session)
.setAvailablePlayerCommands(
                    MediaSession.ConnectionResult.DEFAULT_PLAYER_COMMANDS.buildUpon()
                        .remove(COMMAND_GET_TIMELINE)
                        .remove(COMMAND_GET_TRACKS)
                        .build()
                )
```

But its not helping.

Also I've found solution from this article (https://github.com/androidx/media/issues/158)

but I can't apply it.